# checking java predefined methods

Tags: java, syntax, antlr, system.out

I'm just wondering on how would you check java codes like

```
System.Out.println("hi");
```

it should check if the syntax is correct. I've used a java template in ANTLR, but I'm not quite sure that ANTLR provide checking predefined java methods. Is it possible to check it by using another tool?

Comment: Err, such as javac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't matter which generator you use as long as the grammar describes the language accurately. It's unnecessary to treat built-in classes and methods specially as they are no different than user-defined ones.

Answer (score 1):

The moment your checks start looking at other compilation units you are generally past syntax checking and into semantic checking. A simple grammar parser is not generally able to detect issues like this.

Why not use `javac` directly? Or even the [compiler API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html) provided by modern Java implementations?